# Pipe url parameter into Google Forms

Tags: google-forms, piping

I'm trying to pipe a url parameter such that it appears in a question on a Google Forms. For example, the interaction would be:

```
url= https://..../variable=[word]
```

And then one of the questions in the Google Form would be:

```
What do you think about [word]?
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include built-in functions to do something like that. One alternative is to use Google Apps Script and the HTMLService to build your own form. To learn about this see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/